# SQL Query to aggregate previous results

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table of of data but the results I need are the sum of the previous rows. Each row represents a record of data on a date, and I need the current sum.

Table:

```
+------+-------+--------+
| date | group | change |
+------+-------+--------+
|  0   |   a   |   1    |
+------+-------+--------+
|  0   |   b   |   2    |
+------+-------+--------+
|  1   |   a   |   3    |
+------+-------+--------+
|  1   |   b   |   4    |
+------+-------+--------+
|  2   |   a   |   5    |
+------+-------+--------+
```

Results:

```
+------+-------+-------+
| date | group |  sum  |
+------+-------+-------+
|  0   |   a   |   1   |
+------+-------+-------+
|  0   |   b   |   2   |
+------+-------+-------+
|  1   |   a   |   4   | = 1 + 3
+------+-------+-------+
|  1   |   b   |   6   | = 2 + 4
+------+-------+-------+
|  2   |   a   |   11  | = 1 + 3 + 5
+------+-------+-------+
```

I also need the same result without considering the group:

```
+------+-------+
| date |  sum  |
+------+-------+
|  0   |   3   |
+------+-------+
|  1   |   10  |
+------+-------+
|  2   |   15  |
+------+-------+
```

One more detail to my application is I start with known initial sums for each date/group i.e `max(date)+1`. And I need the sum for consider those values.

I'm currently accomplishing this by running a query:

```
SELECT date, group, sum(change) FROM records GROUP BY date, group ORDER BY date DESC
```

Then in application code I traverse the records backwards starting with the initial sums adding the next date until I get to date_0. This solution works for me, but I'm wondering if I can do this all in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below - [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f7889b9807b436b33cf3be9019d29f9e)

```
select *,sum(change) over(partition by group order by date) as s from t
order by date
```

And for without group -

```
select date,sum(s)
from
(
select *,sum(change) over(partition by group order by date) as s from t
)A group by date
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want a cumulative aggregation.  You can do this as:

```
select date, sum(sum(change)) over (order by date)
from t
group by date;
```